# Yes and No option on Alert Dialog is Missing in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

Im a newbie on Android Programming. Im basically working on our UI but I have this situation wherein the text "Yes/No" is missing but it is functioning. The text are just missing.

[Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JL2E.png)

I just got the code also here on stackoverflow.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
}
public void onBackPressed(){
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
         .setTitle("")
         .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
         .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 finish();
             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("No",null)
         .show();
```

It will be a great help for me if you answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: try calling builder.create() then show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not missing please check your theme color in color.xml may be your colorAccent is white change it to other colour

Comment: Got that! Omg! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For the latest android versions check your theme color in the color.xml file. "colorOnPrimary" color may be white change it to another color